# Why does PathPrefixStrip work when PathPrefix won't?

Tags: traefik, gatsby

I have a GatsbyJS static site built with `--prefix-paths`. The `pathPrefix` is set to `/environment/test` in `gatsby-config.js`. It is deployed to a docker swarm running Traefik.

Adding the following label to the service makes everything run ok:
`traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/environment/test`

I can then browse to `/environment/test` and click around in my GatsbyJs site.

However I find it strange since the backend is build with the path prefix.

Adding the following label does not work:
`traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/environment/test`

Shouldn't it work with `PathPrefix` instead of `PathPrefixStrip`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `pathPrefix` configuration in GatsbyJS means that every link of your website will be prepended with `/environment/test` (see [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)), but this does not mean that on the container running the website, the page is actually hosted on this path.
In your situation, it seems it is not the case.

This means that when connecting via Traefik with the `PathPrefixStrip`, when in your browser you click on a link:

1. The browser requests `/environment/test/page`
2. Traefik translates this to a request to the container for `/page`
3. The container is actually serving files on `/` so it answers with the page

When connecting via Traefik with the `PathPrefix`:

1. The browser requests `/environment/test/page`
2. Traefik translates this to a request to the container for `/environment/test/page`
3. The container is actually serving files on `/` so it doesn't find the page.

Hence, you are confusing the `pathPrefix` setting of a website with the path from which the very same website is served.

The alternative to the current situation would thus be to serve the website under `/environment/test/` and use `PathPrefix` with traefik.