# Nginx file_requested doesn't match request URL

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

I am running traefik in front of multiple microservices in docker containers + a nginx container with traefik path rules to a local service for a development environment. When I run a service locally on port 3000, nginx accepts it's paths and does a `proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000`. This works well for almost everything, except I am having issues with requests for static files, which in this case are `.png` files.

My nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx; worker_processes  auto; pid  /run/nginx.pid;

# Error Log available at error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;    
}

http {

    # Basic
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    log_format  main    'remote_addr:[$remote_addr]  time_local:[$time_local]  upstream_addr:[$upstream_addr]  status:[$status]  bytes_sent:[$body_bytes_sent]  hostname:[$hostname]  file_requested:[$request_filename] ';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/http-access.log  main;

    # Tuning for Performance
    sendfile  on;
    expires off;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;

    # Set Client_Buffer Sizes
    client_body_buffer_size 20K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 16k;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    # Include Site Conf Files
    include /etc/nginx/sites/*.conf; 
}
```

My file in `/etc/nginx/sites`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name traefik.domain;

    location /localservice {
        # Set Proxied Headers to Originals
        proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:3000;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

    location /static/localservice {
        # Set Proxied Headers to Originals
        proxy_pass          http://host.docker.internal:3000;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

}
```

All my files under /microservice are being routed correctly and returning with `200` except those under /static. From the nginx http-access.log I have something strange that I can't figure out:

`remote_addr:[172.17.0.2]  time_local:[13/Jan/2019:00:24:24 +0000]  upstream_addr:[host.ip:3000]  status:[404]  bytes_sent:[7626]  hostname:[f7215dd04bdd]  file_requested:[/etc/nginx/html/logos/image.png]`

This is strange because the request url that is being made is:
`http://traefik.domain/static/localservice/logos/image.png`. Is nginx rewriting the /static from the path somewhere? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with traefik. I had set the `traefik.frontend.rules` programmatically had a `PathPrefixStrip` overwriting my desired rules. I should have read the documentation on [Traefik Matchers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers) a bit more carefully. Also, I found this answer to be very helpful [Why does PathPrefixStrip work when PathPrefix won't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346047/why-does-pathprefixstrip-work-when-pathprefix-wont/50550725)